# how do i fix bash kubectl command not found error massage in cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

[Create and Manage Cloud Resources: Challenge Lab screen shot

im struggling to complete my google cloud challenge because this error : bash kubectl command not found

how do i fix this.
task 3: step 4 : create a Kubernetes services cluster

Answer (score 0):

Try to install latest kubectl [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/.)